# content vanish every time I restart the app

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, persistent

I created a page where I can add exercise for my classes and in this page students can create their custom training (it's a gym app), the only problem is that every time the user closes the app all the training is gone.

I leave below my code, I've done some researches and I kind of understood that there is something with SharPreferences but all the tutorial talk about a login page which is not my case.

can you please advise?? I leave my code below, thanks!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';

class Custom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomState createState() => new _CustomState();
}

class _CustomState extends State<Custom> {
  int _count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _esercizi = List.generate(_count, (int i) => Esercizi());
    bool visible = _count > 0;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Scheda personalizzata'),
          actions: [
            Visibility(
              visible: visible,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.remove_rounded),
                onPressed: _removeNewEsercizi,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: _addNewEsercizi),
          ],
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),
        body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 700,
                    child: ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      children: _esercizi,
                    ),
                  ),
                  //new ContactRow()
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _addNewEsercizi() {
    setState(() {
      _count = _count + 1;
    });
  }

  void _removeNewEsercizi() {
    setState(() {
      _count = _count - 1;
    });
  }
}

class Esercizi extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Esercizi();
}

class _Esercizi extends State<Esercizi> {
  String dropdownValue = 'Seleziona esercizio';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          DropdownButton<String>(
            value: dropdownValue,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey),
            onChanged: (String newValue) {
              setState(() {
                dropdownValue = newValue;
              });
            },
            items: <String>['Seleziona esercizio', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Fo'
                'ur', 'Five', 'Six']
                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 90,
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  cursorColor: Colors.white,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Time/Reps',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey),
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you storing the data?  It looks like it's not being stored anywhere.

Comment: You need to store it in a database

Comment: Can you please link something I can read or watch? 
I’m a beginner so I’m currently try to understand how things work